# Is FB App Review necessary for read only website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I'm creating a website which show a single Facebook page content in the homepage (events basic informations, photos and the five latest instagram photos). Do I have to submit an App Review? If yes, what permissions do I need?

There is no FB login request in the site and no content is published using it. No FB/Instagram user information is shown.

Thanks,
Alessio

**EDIT:**

Here is my code. It's the same for every endpoint

```
function loadFacebookEvents(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            fbEvents=JSON.parse(this.responseText).data;

            renderFacebookEvents()
            //loadFacebookPhotos()
        }
    };
    //events
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/thecagelivorno/events?time_filter=upcoming&fields=cover,description,end_time,name,start_time,ticket_uri,place&access_token=<my-access-token>", true);



    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: why not just try without review? please add your code.

Comment: I'm currently using the APIs without app review and it's working but I fear they'll block my app if i don't submit the app review. I'll add my code asap

Comment: if it works, then it works. but what you are doing right now is very very wrong. you are hardcoding an access token in client code, right? tokens are meant to be kept secret. also, you should not call the api for every single page hit. with a lot of users, you would definitely hit api limits. you need to do that call server side and implement some caching.

Comment: ok, thanks for your advices. I will implement a cache feature for sure. Just to be sure: i forgot to mention that my app is currently in test mode. Should I switch to live in order to verify its correct behavior?

Comment: again, if it works, then it works. no need to put it live actually, if you just get the events of your page with the api.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot :)